# How to set maxRequestLength and maxAllowedContentLength for specific location in asp.net mvc, web.config file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, file-upload, web-config

I have an ASP.Net MVC 4 app that I need to be able upload large files in specific action.
The route in question is '~/UploadArea/UploadController/UploadAction' and the config I have setup looks like this:

```
<location path="~/UploadArea/UploadController/UploadAction">
<system.web>
  <!-- maxRequestLength is in kilobytes (KB)  -->
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="100000" />
  <!-- 100MB -->
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <!-- maxAllowedContentLength is in bytes (B)  -->
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="100000000"/>
      <!-- 100MB -->
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
</location>
```

If I don't use location and use the config for whole app it just works fine otherwise nothing happens, where is the problem in setting  node?

Answer (score -2):

change your path to be the controller/action only, drop the ~/ as that, I believe, forces IIS to look for a literal file path that matches.
so depending on your routing and how the page is called it could be:

```
<location path="UploadController/UploadAction">
```

or if it is the default action and is requested just as mysite/UploadController then try:

```
<location path="UploadController">
```

Comment: Thanks TheZenker, I tried both "UploadController/UploadAction" and "UploadController" with no luck... but when I tried "UploadArea/UploadController" everything worked fine, wondering why "UploadAction" is not default action of "UploadController" and just requested as "http://www.domain.com/UploadArea/UploadController/UploadAction"... anyways, thanks for the reply.